# Prevent Windows from installing 20H2

Tags: windows, updates

How to prevent the installation of Windows 10, version 20H2 update? I know this version causes frequent unsolvable bluescreens for my gear (ASROCK P67 PRO3).

[image]

Comment: I would try to update UEFI before anything else. There's really no way to definitely prevent Windows updates.

Comment: Click on Pause and pause the restart. Then use the time to update drivers.  See if that helps with getting the Windows updates to not conflict.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've read in my native language that updating UEFI doesn't solve this problem with BSODs. [source](https://www.fixitpc.pl/topic/35392-windows-10-pro-ver-20h2-kmode-exception-not-handled/)

Comment: @John thanks! I haven't thought about pausing updates. I have additional 7 days for researching the problem.

Comment: @karlosos - You are aware that eventually you will have to install a future feature update.  If you are running 2004 it absolutely should not be causing BSOD since 20H2 can be enabled through an enablement package.  Additionally, 21H1 will also be an enablement package when its released.  Preventing 20H2 is a temporary solution that won’t be a permanent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To abort a Windows upgrade**

- Run Settings
- Type `Security and Maintenance` and select it when displayed
- Select "Maintenance" to expand it
- Under the heading "Automatic Maintenance", select "Stop Maintenance"

**To postpone indefinitely Windows Update**

- Open *Settings > Network & Internet > Status*
- Click on the "Properties" button below your internet connection
- Toggle the "Set as metered connection" option to On.